# Show object only on certain frames by script

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I am trying to figure out how to write a script where I can set an array of frames on which the object is rendered and hide it from render on the rest.

fe. [1, 2, 3, 7] => the object would render only on frames 1,2,3 and 7.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code might look like

```py
import bpy

visible = [ 1, 2, 3, 7 ]


# Assume that the active object is the one being hidden
object = bpy.context.active_object

# Initialize to hidden.  You can delete this if your first visible frame is frame 1
object.hide_render = True
object.keyframe_insert("hide_render", frame = 0)

# Walk through the array, adding keyframes
for frame in visible:
    object.hide_render = False
    object.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_render", frame=frame)
    object.hide_render = True
    object.keyframe_insert("hide_render", frame = frame+1)
```

That hides the object from the render for every frame except those in the list.

This works because render visibility is called `hide_render` and is `False` when the object is visible in the render and `True` when it is hidden.  So we unhide it and set a keyframe.  Since you only want it visible on specific keyframes, we advance to the next frame, hide it again, and set a keyframe.

The initial hide is in case there are frames between the start and where you first want to display the object.  Your example starts at 1, so you don't need this code, but if you started at a later frame you would.